# Displaying intersection from FME LineOnAreaOverlayer transformer in FMEViewer and ArcMap is different?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, fme-form

I have one very interesting issue which I do not know how to solve/understand. In FME I used the `LineOnAreaOverlayer` transformer to get new intersected lines, these some are inside and outside polygons. When I visualize it with FMEViewer and visualize them with ArcMAP I get different results.

In ArcMAP it is visible like line was not intersected according to the polygon, but at the same time in FMEViewer everything is fine.
help please!

[image: This is situation within FMEViever]

[image: And this is within ArcMAP]

Both representing same line and area.

And I tried to do intersection within ArcMap and intersections occures at the same place as with FME:

[image: intersected with ArcMap]

Comment: Screenshots might be helpful.

Comment: What format are you viewing the fme export in ArcMap as shapefile?

Comment: Filegeodatabase as a format. So after running FME workspace I get one polyline fc class which polylines should be splitted over polygons.
I am wondering if LineOnAreaOverlayer does its job 100% correct?!

Comment: I have to find the way how to insert images here

Comment: Can anyone help me how to set up screenshot here?

Comment: When editing the question press Ctrl+G or click on the picture icon on the top bar to open the add picture dialogue. Or if you are having problems with that, paste in the image hyperlinks and someone will inline them for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Oh I tried to add picture here in comment box.

Comment: What scales are the screenshots at? What projection are you using in FME? What projection are you using in ArcGIS? What is the spatial resolution on the two feature classes?

Comment: you might want to also try https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/fmetalk

Comment: Spatial resolution is the same for both fcs. But, for example, If i load data for one feature from one dataset to another, and Spatial Resolution is different, should I get some message in AcrCatalog about this difference? Or it just load data, no mather what kind of spat.res. is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you writing the data to Geodatabase and then viewing that in the FME Viewer, or are you sending the data directly to the FME Viewer from the workspace? Really these are two different things.

For example, if you see the results correctly when sending the data directly, but it looks like ArcGIS when you open the Geodatabase to view it, then the issue is obviously in writing out the data (and the overlayer is correct).

If the two look the same (and are correct) when viewing in FME Viewer, then I would look to ArcGIS for the issue.

To be honest, my best guess is that the resolution isn't fine enough to record the point exactly at that location, and it's shifted/snapped to the nearest grid position during writing.

Comment: Yes. It looks like this was problem, although spatial resultion was the same for to datasets (checked in ArcMap) but datasets came from different sources. So I fixed it with creating/validating topology. And that was partial soultion. Next I did, is changing manually geometry of critical objects. But what will be the most professional solution, I do not know. My apologize I forgot to answer here (too busy).